# How to put voice captured text into textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

This is a complicated question, but here goes. I built a jquery chat feature where I type something into a textfield tag and hit send and it goes into a chat box. That is done.

I just found a voice to text library using a javascript.
http://ctrlq.org/code/19680-html5-web-speech-api

My problem is that I do not know how to put all the required html tags inside the textfield tag...i dont think its possible...or maybe i'm wrong.

Here is how the code works as of now (without the voice) https://jsfiddle.net/v3Lru135/

Here is the code with the voice and my attempt at adding the html tags https://jsfiddle.net/9r93vcsq/

Can somebody help me get it so when i push that button and start talking it puts what i say in text form into the textfield so i can hit send.... Thank you

```
<div id="chatContainer">

     </div>

     <div id="chatControls">

     <!--<textarea id="chatTextBox" placeholder = "Enter your message   
here..."> </textarea>-->

<div id="chatTextBox">
     <div>
      <a href="#" id="start_button"  
onclick="startDictation(event)">Dictate</a>
    </div>

    <div id="results">
      <span id="final_span" class="final"></span>
      <span id="interim_span" class="interim"></span>
    </div>
  </div>


     <button id="chatSend">Send</button>

#chatContainer{
    width: 95%;
    height: 50px;
    background: url(../assets/chatTile.png) repeat;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
    padding: 5px;
}
#chatTextBox{
    resize: none;
    width: 65%;
    height: 35px !important;
    float: left;
    opacity: .9;
}
#chatControls{
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#chatSend{
    resize: none !important;
    width: 50%;
    height: 35px !important;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 30%;
    float: right;
    opacity: .9;
    padding: 5px;
}


.chatUsername{
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.botMan{
    color: #424242;
    font-weight: bold;
}



var canned = ["Ok, how is this?" , "You're welcome!"]

$(function() {

  // grab a reference to the chat
  var chat = $("#chatContainer")

  // add a click handler to send messages
  $("#chatSend").click(function() {

    var username = "<span class=chatUsername>CNN_News: </span>"
      , newMessage = $("#chatTextBox").val() + '<br>'
      , delay = 4000

    // reset the input
    $("#chatTextBox").val("")

    // render the chat
    chat.append(username + newMessage)
    chat.scrollTop(chat.prop("scrollHeight"))

    // set a timeout to send a canned response

    setTimeout(function() {
      chat.append('<span class=botMan>StarkFan: </span>' + 
canned.shift() + '<br>')
      chat.scrollTop(chat.prop("scrollHeight"))
    }, delay)

  // end of click handler
  })
})















var final_transcript = '';
var recognizing = false;

if ('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window) {

  var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();

  recognition.continuous = true;
  recognition.interimResults = true;

  recognition.onstart = function() {
    recognizing = true;
  };

  recognition.onerror = function(event) {
    console.log(event.error);
  };

  recognition.onend = function() {
    recognizing = false;
  };

  recognition.onresult = function(event) {
    var interim_transcript = '';
    for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
      if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
        final_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
      } else {
        interim_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
      }
    }
    final_transcript = capitalize(final_transcript);
    final_span.innerHTML = linebreak(final_transcript);
    interim_span.innerHTML = linebreak(interim_transcript);

  };
}

var two_line = /\n\n/g;
var one_line = /\n/g;
function linebreak(s) {
  return s.replace(two_line, '<p></p>').replace(one_line, '<br>');
}

function capitalize(s) {
  return s.replace(s.substr(0,1), function(m) { return m.toUpperCase(); });
}

function startDictation(event) {
  if (recognizing) {
    recognition.stop();
    return;
  }
  final_transcript = '';
  recognition.lang = 'en-US';
  recognition.start();
  final_span.innerHTML = '';
  interim_span.innerHTML = '';
}
```

Comment: See "Frameworks & Extensions" https://jsfiddle.net/26cmcugy/1/ ; jsfiddle not appear to have jQuery loaded into document. Tried utilizing `.text()` on `final_transcript` , after `html` compiled within `final_transcript` ?

Comment: oh my bad I will redo the js fiddles

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you could modify the example given on the site to fit your needs: http://www.labnol.org/software/add-speech-recognition-to-website/19989/

```
  function startDictation() {

    if (window.hasOwnProperty('webkitSpeechRecognition')) {

      var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();

      recognition.continuous = false;
      recognition.interimResults = false;

      recognition.lang = "en-US";
      recognition.start();

      recognition.onresult = function(e) {
         // commented out the old commands, your new command is below these comments
         // document.getElementById('transcript').value = e.results[0][0].transcript;
         // recognition.stop();
         // document.getElementById('labnol').submit();
         $("#chatTextBox").val(e.results[0][0].transcript); // set the input val to the speech transcript
      };

      recognition.onerror = function(e) {
        recognition.stop();
      }

    }
  }
```

If this does not work, we can try debugging by printing the contents of `results`.